# Do there exist deficient-perfect square numbers whose deficiency is also a square (and not one)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

This is a follow-up to this MSE question:

[How often does $D(n^2) = m^2$ happen, where $D(x)$ is the deficiency of $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2340824)

Here is my question in this post:

> **Do there exist examples for which $D(n^2) = m^2$ and $m \mid n$, where $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m > 1$?**

**MY ATTEMPT**

In the linked MSE question, the following examples for $D(n^2) = m^2$ (without the divisibility constraint) were given:

$$(m_1, n_1) = (19, 46), m_1 \nmid n_1$$
$$(m_2, n_2) = (53, 284), m_2 \nmid n_2$$
$$(m_3, n_3) = (3509, 149728), m_3 \nmid n_3$$
$$(m_4, n_4) = (6479, 242656), m_4 \nmid n_4$$
$$(m_5, n_5) = (1583, 1633), m_5 \nmid n_5$$
$$(m_6, n_6) = (223309, 260495), m_6 \nmid n_6$$

Rephrasing my question a bit, I have:

> **Do there exist [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816) square numbers whose [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) is also a square (and not one)?**

**Added on July 09 2017** I have the following bounds for $D(n^2)/n^2$ in terms of an auxiliary variable $q$:

$$\frac{2}{q+1} \leq \frac{D(n^2)}{n^2} < \frac{2}{q}.$$

The conditions specified in my problem imply that

$$\frac{2}{q+1} = \frac{m^2}{n^2}.$$

**Added on July 12 2017 - MOTIVATION**

When $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, then the following equations hold:
$$\gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right)=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}.$$
(This is proved in this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01868.pdf), to appear in [NNTDM](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/).)

In particular, when the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $k=\nu_{q}(N)=1$ is true, then $D(n^2) \mid n^2$.

In the other direction, [Broughan, et. al (page 7, Lemma 8)](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf) proved that if $$\frac{\sigma(N/q^k)}{q^k}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}$$
is a square, then $k=1$.

Putting these all together, under the assumption that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square, we have that
$$1 < m^2 = D(n^2) \mid n^2.$$

Now, [MSE user Matthew Conroy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2937) checked all $n < {10}^7$ and found only one ODD deficient-perfect square (other than $1$), namely $n^2 = {3003}^2 = 9018009$, with deficiency $819$.  (Notice that the deficiency is *not* a square.)

All other deficient-perfect squares are powers of $2$, up to $n < {10}^7$.  Indeed, if $n = 2^k$ for some integer $k \geq 0$, then $n^2$ is deficient-perfect with deficiency $1$.

Comment: @MatthewConroy, I have bounds for $D(n^2)/n^2$ in terms of an auxiliary variable $q$. Does that help?

Comment: Why don't you add information you have to the question?

Comment: I don't understand your addition.  What is $q$? How does it relate to $n$?

Comment: @MatthewConroy, kindly refer to http://arnienumbers.blogspot.com/2017/03/on-biconditional-for-odd-perfect.html.

Comment: I still do not understand.  It appears that $q$ and $n$ are related via $N=q^kn^2$, where $N$ is an odd perfect number? What if there is no such $N$?

Comment: The underlying assumption is of course that there exists such an $N$, then we can try to logically derive necessary consequences of such an assumption.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61848/discussion-between-jose-arnaldo-bebita-dris-and-matthew-conroy).

Comment: Editing in a motivation for the question now to help the readers see how odd perfect numbers enter the picture...