# Question about a result on odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

In the paper titled [*Improving the Chen and Chen result for odd perfect numbers*](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/n39/n39.pdf) (Lemma 8, page 7), Broughan et al. show that if
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}$$
is a square, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$, then $k=1$.

Is it then possible to derive the implication
$$D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2) \text{ is a square } \implies k=1?$$

I could only derive the equation
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}$$
where $s(q^k) = \sigma(q^k) - q^k = \sigma(q^{k-1})$.

**Added August 25 2018**

I also currently know that
$$D(n^2) \mid n^2 \iff k=1.$$

That is, the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture is true for the odd perfect number $q^k n^2$ if and only if the non-Euler factor $n^2$ is [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816).

**Added July 07 2019**

If
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}$$
is a square, then by Broughan et al.'s result, we have $k=1$, which implies that
$$s(q^k) = \sigma(q^k) - q^k = \sigma(q) - q = (q+1) - q = 1$$
is a square.
Consequently, if $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square, then $D(n^2)$ is a square too.

Comment: This [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2341424) is closely related to the present one.