# Question about a result on odd perfect numbers - Part II

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, square-numbers, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(This question is an offshoot of this [earlier one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2886597).)

In the paper titled [*Improving the Chen and Chen result for odd perfect numbers*](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf) (Lemma 8, page 7), Broughan et al. show that if
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}$$
is a square, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$, then $k=1$.  (That $q$ is the special/Euler prime means that $q$ satisfies $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$, which means that $q \geq 5$.)

It is fairly easy to show that, in general, we have
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$, so that assuming $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square, we have $k=1$ by Broughan et al.'s result, and so we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}=\frac{n^2}{(q+1)/2}=D(n^2) \text{ is a square }.$$
Hence, $(q+1)/2$ is also a square.  Using the identity
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{A-C}{B-D},$$
where $B \neq 0$, $D \neq 0$, and $B \neq D$, we get
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2) - n^2}{(q-1)/2}=D(n^2) \text{ is a square }.$$

Here is my question:

> **Does it follow that $\sigma(n^2) - n^2$ and $(q-1)/2$ are also squares?**

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since 
$$\frac{q+1}{2} - \frac{q-1}{2} = 1$$
and $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $(q-1)/2$ and $(q+1)/2$ are consecutive integers.  If they were both squares, then
$$\bigg(\frac{q-1}{2} = 0\bigg) \land \bigg(\frac{q+1}{2} = 1\bigg)$$
which implies that $q=1$.  This contradicts $q \geq 5$.

Thus, $(q-1)/2$, and therefore $\sigma(n^2) - n^2$, are *not* squares.

*Follow-Up Question*

> **Does this proof suffice?**

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @Peter.  $(q+1)/2$ is a square since
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}$$
is a square, by assumption.  Appealing to Broughan et al.'s result alluded to in the hyperlinked paper, then if $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a square, it follows that $k=1$, so that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{n^2}{(q+1)/2} \text{ is a square }.$$
Hence, $(q+1)/2$ is a perfect square, if $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is a perfect square.

Comment: @Peter:  I invite you to write out your comments as an actual answer to this question, so that I may be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have that $$\frac{q+1}{2}$$ and $$\frac{q-1}{2}$$ are both perfect squares and $\ q\ $ is odd, then in fact we have two consecutive integers, which can only be $\ 0\ $ and $\ 1\ $.

Hence, indeed we can conclude $\ q=1\ $ which is a contradiction.

So, your proof is valid.